# Problem understanding the owner assignment

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, contract-deployment

Suppose I have 3 contracts, namely Owner, B and C:

```
contract Owned {
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}
```

**Contract B**

```
contract B is Onwed{
     constructor() public{
        uint256 totalSupply = 10000000000;     // any amount
     }
}
```

**Contract C**

*I want to create an instance of `contract B`, in contract C. There are  2 ways to do it*

```
contract C{
     constructor() public{
          B instance = B(address_of_deployed_B);  // Method 1
          B instance = new B();                   // Method 2
          B instance2 = new B();                  // 2 instances of B
    }

}
```

What I actually want here is, the `owner` of the contract is set to `contract C's address`.

But the following is happening.

**Method 1** works fine when I try to instantiate this way, *but since it's already deployed, I can't set owner properly*. 
**Method 2** is not able to deploy 2 instances of the contract in the constructor(shows revert).

[Edit 1] **Method 2** is working fine. But it isn't working if you initialise 2 instances of the same contract.

Comment: It shows `txn mined but the execution failed` in remix IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that it runs out of gas.

Maybe, in this case, it works, but if you have big contracts like `ERC20 TOKEN`, it may go out of gas and may not get deployed.